# Get all fields from table and mark some under specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables:

First table is named `FIELDS` and has following two columns:

1. `FIELD_ID` whose data-type is `int`
2. `FIELD_NAME` whose data-type is `varchar`

Second table is named `SHIPPINGS` and has following two columns:

1. `FIELD_ID` whose data-type is `int`
2. `SHIPPING_ID` whose data-type is `int`

I need to retrieve all field names, and mark those which have certain `SHIPPING_ID` set in table `SHIPPINGS`.

Example:

[image: Table fields][image: Table shipping]

If I will choose `SHIPPING_ID = 3`, I'd like to receive the following structure:

```
s_firstname true

b_lastname false

s_lastname false
```

How do I do this? I have tried the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT pf.field_name, ps.shipping_id, IF(ps.shipping_id = 3, "true", "false") AS status
FROM `fields` AS pf LEFT JOIN `shippings` AS ps
ON ps.shipping_id = 3
```

But it returns true for all fields.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select f.*, (s.field_id is not null) as has_3
from fields f left join
     shippings s
     on f.field_id = s.field_id and s.shipping_id = 3;
```

Note:  This interprets the results as wanting a boolean value.  If you want a string, then use a `case` expression:

```
select f.*,
       (case when s.field_id is not null then 'true' else 'false end) as has_3
```